# How to Use VBA to Loop goal seek down columns

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this site and brand new to VBA. I have a question related to goal seek.

I need to use Goal seek in VBA several times. Here is a sample of my Excel Sheet:

[image: Excel sheet]

I need to set the cells in F(which is a formula linked to another sheet) to 0, by changing the cells in I (hardcoded). I have the basic code to do this, but I want to figure out how to tell Excel "hey, loop this action for every cell in the column". I don't want to have to manually put this command in VBA hundreds of times. Here is what I actually have in VBA.

```
Sub Goal_Seek()
'
' Goal_Seek Macro

    Range("F7").Select
    Range("F7").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("I7")
    Range("F8").Select
    Range("F8").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("I8")
     Range("F9").Select
    Range("F9").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("I9")
     Range("F10").Select
    Range("F10").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("I10")
     Range("F11").Select
    Range("F11").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("I11")
End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
Sub Goal_Seek()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 7 To lastRow
            .Range("F" & i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range("I" & i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you saying to put this before the set of commands that I have?

Comment: No - this should be it. The `For` loop does what you want.

Comment: Can you point me to somewhere where I can learn about the syntax?— for ex: what’s “as long” and what’s .end(xlup).row? Finally “For... next” thanks!

Comment: Maybe [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/looping-through-a-range-of-cells)

Comment: Thanks! This was super helpful. One thing... Sometimes goal seek cannot find a solution and I will have to go back and do those manually. How can I tell Excel "if you can't find a solution that sets the cell equal to the target value ("0") get as close as you can? I'm thinking of adding a second sub that has excel go back and relook at the cells that gave it trouble the first time??