# Goal Seek Macro Scanning Across Columns

Tags: excel, vba

[Recently, I asked how to write a macro that will loop goal seek when its organized in rows.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53418253/5223757) I now want to loop goal seek across columns. I have the following code so far.

```
Sub Goal_Seek()
    Dim lastcol As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastcol = .Cells(.Columns.Count, "4").End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = K To lastcol
            .Range(i & "4").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Range(i & "4")
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is my Excel.
[image: Spreadsheet with data in K4:N6]

I want to set the "variance" equal to zero by changing K4. I then want the macro to move one column right and keep doing goal seek until the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` should be a `Long`, not a letter, and use `Cells` instead of `Range`. Note that the *1st* argument of `Cells` is the row index, and the *2nd* is the column index.

```
Sub Goal_Seek()
    Dim lastcol As Long, i As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        lastcol = .Cells(4, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For i = 11 To lastcol
            .Cells(6, i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Cells(4, i)
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! But what does the "11" mean? My data is only in rows 4-6. I'm confused

Comment: Column K is the 11th column. You're looping through columns, not rows.

Comment: I test ran the macro once, and it worked successfully. However I reset and now its saying "Run-time error. Reference isn't valid". I don't understand."Cells(6, i).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=.Cells(4, i)" is highlighted as a part of the error

Comment: What did you do to "reset" it?

Comment: I think I got it now.... In Excel I just added 50 to the disturb. Row to get the variance to a non zero number. Then I reran it. I ended up just closing the file and repasting the VBA. Its working fine now. Thanks again for your help